# Can a computer make a proof by induction?

Tags: math, proofs, automated-theorem-proving

Can a computer solve the following problem, i.e. make a proof by induction? And why?

> Prove by **induction** that $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2, \, \, \, \forall n\in\mathbb N .$$

I'm doing a Ph.D. in pure maths. I love coding when I wanna have some fun, but I've never got too far in this field. I say my background because maybe there's someone who wants to explain this in a more abstract language there's a chance that I will understand it.

Comment: Are you looking for **any** technique that is able to prove that statement, i.e. you are not necessarily looking for a machine learning approach, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for some classes of problems. For instance, [WolframAlpha can generate an induction proof](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Prove%20%20by%20induction%20sum%20of%20k%5E3%20from%201%20to%20n%20%3D%20%28n%28n%2B1%29%29%5E2%2F2) to the problem posed in the question.

According to the author of this proof generator, he built a library of pattern-matched proofs to generate the proofs. More details about his approach can be find in [his write-up about the problem](https://blog.wolfram.com/2016/07/14/behind-wolframalphas-mathematical-induction-based-proof-generator/).

Other alternative (thought not induction-based) for automatically verifying these kind of identities (in special, hypergeometric identities) is by using algorithms such as Zeilberger's method along with the HYPER algorithm, both described in the excellent book [A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html), currently available for free by one of its co-authors.

Answer (score 3):

There are programming languages that allow you to verify a proof by induction. For example, I used  [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/), but I'm sure there are also others.